# synchronization validation and display of dialog in a PrimeFaces JSF2.0 form

Tags: forms, validation, jsf-2, dialog

I have a form with jsf2 and primefaces that contains a submit button that managed two things:
First: form validation with the update attribute and second launching a confirmation dialog box when validation succeeded and all of this are managed by:

```
update="myfieldset display"
```

so my problem is that when I click into the button validation: if validation don't succeeded : validation messages are displayed in the form : ok
but if the validation succeeded I must click a second time to display dialog box

anyone know how to solve this problem there?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">



    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function effacer(formulaire){
            for (var i=0; i<formulaire.length; i++){
                if (formulaire.elements[i].type=="input" || formulaire.elements[i].type=="textarea" ) {formulaire.elements[i].value="";}
            }
            document.getElementById('contenu_input').value="";
        }
        //-->
    </script>

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template_utilisateur.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form id="form" prependId="false" >  
                    <p:fieldset  id="myfieldset" legend="Nouveau message">

                        <p:messages id="msgs"/>

                        <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                            <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Titre : *"/> 
                            <p:inputText id="title" style="width:340px;" value="#{messageController.titre}" required="true" requiredMessage="veuillez saisir un titre" label="Titre">  
                                <f:validateLength minimum="10" />  
                            </p:inputText>  
                            <p:message for="title" display="icon"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="city" value="Destinataire : *" /> 
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{messageController.destinataire}" label="Destinataire" required="true" requiredMessage="veuillez choisir au moins un destinataire" >  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Séléctionner déstinataire" itemValue="" />  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{messageController.users}" />    
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  
                            <p:message for="city" id="msgSurname3" display="icon"/>

                            <h:outputLabel for="comm" value="Lié a La commande N° : " /> 
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="comm" label="Commande"  value="#{messageController.idComm}"  >  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Aucune commande" itemValue="" />  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{messageController.id_c}" />    
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  
                            <p:message for="comm" id="msgSurnamse3" display="icon"/>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputLabel for="contenu" value="Contenu : *" /> 
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <p:editor id="contenu" widgetVar="editer" value="#{messageController.message}" width="600" required="true" requiredMessage="Veuillez saisir le contenu du message" >
                                <f:validateLength minimum="10" /> 
                            </p:editor>  
                            <p:message for="contenu" id="editorm" display="icon"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid columns="3">  
                            <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="envoyer" update="myfieldset display"  onclick="#{messageController.retournerDialog()}" icon="ui-icon-disk" />  
                            <p:commandButton id="clearButton" type="reset" value="initialiser" onclick="editer.clear()"  
                                             icon="ui-icon-close" /> 
                        </h:panelGrid>  

                    </p:fieldset>  

                    <p:dialog header="Confirmation" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" modal="true">  
                        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="1" cellpadding="4">
                            <h:outputText value="Titre : " />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{messageController.titre}" id="model"/>  

                            <h:outputText value="Déstinataire :" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{messageController.destinataire}" id="year"/>  

                            <h:outputText value="Lié à la commande N° : " />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{messageController.idComm}" id="manufacturer"/>  

                            <h:outputText value="Contenu :" />  
                            <h:outputText id="displxcay" value="#{messageController.message}" escape="false" />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                    </p:dialog>  

                </h:form>  

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here the method to launch the dialog

```
public String retournerDialog(){
    String retour = "";
    if( getDestinataire() != "" && getMessage()!= "" && getTitre()!="" && getMessage().length()>9 && getTitre().length()>9){
        retour="dlg.show()";
    }
    return retour;
    }
```

thank you in advance

---

**Update**: thank you BalusC for your detailed response,  I tested both of your answers but they don't work 
here is the code of the button :

```
<p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="envoyer" update="myfieldset, display" action="#{messageController.showDialog}"  icon="ui-icon-disk" />
```

and the managedBean :

```
 private boolean showDialog;

public void showDialog() {
    showDialog = true;
}

public boolean isShowDialog() {
    return showDialog;
}
```

and with this code above the dialog doesn't appear even if validation is succeeded
 :  I think because action must return outcome string not boolean
and when I make :

```
<p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="envoyer" update="myfieldset, display" onclick="dlg.show();"  icon="ui-icon-disk" />
```

it appear even if the validation failed

and to remind you 
when I put a method above like this :

```
<p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="envoyer" update="myfieldset, display" onclick="#{messageController.retournerDialog()}"  icon="ui-icon-disk" />
```

I have to click twice (I think one for validation and one for displaying dialog)for the dialog is displayed

also in the official documentation : they use this dialog with onclick attribute

do you have any other idea

Comment: honestly, I didn't understand well your comment, can you sujjest me a solution of this problem, thanks

Comment: but if I put just update='dialog' without myfielset the form doesn't be validate

Comment: when I put update='dialog' it works but validation don't work, and when I put both only validation that works

Comment: and the daialog works but after the second click

Comment: please , can you suggest me another solution because I m stuck for several days ?